# Error using glmfit : X and Y must have same number of observation

Tags: matlab, glm

I am intended to apply global linear model using glmfit in matlab on my image.

Error using glmfit (line 227)
Number of observations in X and Y must match.

Error in changed (line 10)
b = glmfit(gchanel,trainingAns(:),'normal'); %binomial   normal% see the output of the model based on the training

Below is my code.

```
image = imread('21.tif');           %Input Image
trainingAns = imread('21.gif');     % Ground Truth
gchanel = image(:,:,2);

%%  ＧＬＭ
szG = size(gchanel);
b = glmfit(gchanel,trainingAns(:),'normal'); %binomial   normal% see the output of the model based on the training
featuresCTrain = glmval(b,gchanel,'logit');
CTrain = reshape(CTrain,szG(1:2));

features = reshape(gchanel,[prod(szG(1:2)),1]);
```

I know what X and Y are. X is a matrix on which I have to do the prediction and Y is a vector of responses on a true image (trainingAns in my case) . Kindly help me solve this error.
Below is the attached figure of ground truth '21.gif'. enter image description here

[image]

Comment: According to [**`glmfit`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/glmfit.html) doc,  X is an n-by-p matrix  and y can be n-by-1 vector or a two column matrix,.... . Now see what dimensions of  `gchanel` and `trainingAns(:)` you have. Clearly it's not in accordance with nxp and nx1 for `gchanel` and `trainingAns(:)` respectively. Read the documentation.

Comment: @SardarUsama I read the documentation. gchanel has dimension of 584 x 565. and trainingAns(:) is 329960 x1 . As I have to convert trainingAns to vector that is why I did trainingAns(:). How can I make number of rows equal in TrainingAns and gchanel?

Comment: 584 is not equal to 329960. That's where your problem is! *How to make them equal?* Select 584 rows of `trainingAns(:)` but you should know what you really are doing. (But I really doubt that you'd be looking for the result it will give). Also see [MCVE]

Comment: @SardarUsama I have posted the code in my original question. and I have to enhance the contrast as i said. But i am not able to solve this issue.Taking oput only 584 from trainingAns(:) will give the correct results? I mean it will discard alot of rows.

Comment: that code is not a [MCVE]

Comment: Also you shouldn't expect people to read the research paper for you and come up with a solution. You should provide the relevant parts of the paper here and provide the link as a reference

Comment: @SardarUsama thankyou for your suggestions. I have made edits accordingly. Can you check it now? And for the input image it is in .tif format. So I am not able to attach it. Is there a way of attaching it?

Comment: I think the problem is not with .tif format but with the size of the file. I think that its size is greater than 2MB. Upload it directly to http://imgur.com/ if not possible with the default interface